# How to configure Expo to allow global module imports?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am looking for a way to get rid of these

```
import { get_records } from ../../../../store/actions/async';
```

To be honest I tried a lot of tricks:

- Using a `package.json` in the `src/` with `{"name": "@app"}` and trying to use:

  ```
  import { get_records } from '@app/store/actions/async';
  ```
- Using the React Native AppRegistry name:

  ```
   import { get_records } from 'main/src/store/actions/async';
  ```

The same questions goes for assets.

I've seen solution  with Webpack and Babel but I don't use them with React Native.

How do you manage to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using Babel with RN?

Comment: @riwu you are right, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was using Babel without noticing.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
npm install --save-dev eslint-import-resolver-babel-module
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "~mobile": "./src",
        "~assets": "./assets"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "babel-module": {
          "alias": {
            "~mobile": "./src",
            "~assets": "./assets"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then I use it like that:

```
import { addToFavorite, removeFromFavorite } from '~mobile/store/actions';

await Font.loadAsync({
  'cabin-reg': require('~assets/fonts/Cabin/Cabin-Regular.ttf'),
  'league-spartan': require('~assets/fonts/LeagueSpartan/leaguespartan-bold.ttf')
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Expo, you must be using babel because only ES6 version of the libraries are shipped. Even projects created with `react-native init` come with babel by default. Check your project folder, it should have a `.babelrc` file.

You can then use [babel-plugin-root-import](https://github.com/entwicklerstube/babel-plugin-root-import):

```
import { get_records } from '~/store/actions/async';
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-root-import",
      {
        "rootPathSuffix": "src"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```